# Prove that this set is a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, characteristic-functions

> Let $X$ be a set and $\mathcal{B}$ a subset of the set of maps from $X$ to $\mathbb{Z}_2$.
>
> For any subset $A\subset X$ we define the characteristic mapping of A as the mapping $\chi_A:X\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_2$ given by $\chi_A(x)=1$ if $x\in A$ and $\chi_A(x)=0$ if $x\notin A$.
>
> Give $\mathcal{B}$ the operations:
>
> $\odot: \mathcal{B} \times \mathcal{B} \rightarrow \mathcal{B}$ given by $(\chi_A \odot \chi_B)(x)=\chi_A(x) \cdot \chi_B(x)$ and
>
> $\oplus : \mathcal{B} \times \mathcal{B} \rightarrow \mathcal{B}$ given by $(\chi_A \oplus \chi_B)(x)=\chi_A(x) + \chi_B(x) - \chi_A(x) \cdot \chi_B(x)$.
>
> **Show that $\mathcal{B}$ whith these operations is a ring**.

As a part of this exercise, we have to see that $(\mathcal{B},\oplus)$ is a group.

I have considered the map $\chi_\emptyset$ as the neutral element for the addition $\oplus$ since $\chi_\emptyset (x)=0$ $\forall x \in X$.

But I have a problem when I try to find an opposite element because $\chi_A(x) + \chi_B(x) - \chi_A(x) \cdot \chi_B(x)$ has to be $0$ but it only happens if $x\in A^c \cap B^c$. So, what is our candidate for be an opposite of $\chi_A$ and how can I denote it? Is it correct to consider the map $\chi_\emptyset$ as the neutral element?

Comment: It's itself: $-\chi_A=\chi_A$.

Comment: @Berci I have written $\mathbb{Z}_2$, but the original statement sais $\{0,1\}$. So I am not sure if we can consider that it is the same. Because $-\chi_A$ can take values $0$ and $-1$ that are in $\mathbb{Z}_2$. But if we consider the set $\{0,1\}$ instead $\mathbb{Z}_2$?

Comment: What I mean is simply that $\chi_A\oplus \chi_A=0=\chi_\emptyset$.

Comment: Hi Claudia, it is fine to only consider {0,1} as a set here, as for all values of $x,y \in \{0,1\}$, $x + y - xy \in \{0,1\}$, and $xy \in \{0,1\}$ too.

Comment: Hmm.. You may be right. What I know is that $\chi_A\oplus \chi_B=x\mapsto \chi_A(x) +\chi_B(x)$ where addition is performed in $\Bbb Z_2$ makes a (so called Boolean) ring structure with the given multiplication. I doubt any other (naturally defined) addition could work.

Comment: What if you consider $X$ with one only element, so that the only characteristic functions are $\chi_X\equiv 1$ and $\chi_\varnothing\equiv 0$. In this case, $\chi_X$ doesn't look like having an inverse.

Comment: It makes perfect sense if $\{0,1\}$ is endowed with the Boolean operations $\cdot, +, -$: see my updated answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you correctly observed, this definition doesn't produce additive inverses, for example $\chi_X$ doesn't have inverse, **unless** we interpret $\cdot, +, -$ as *Boolean operations* 'meet', 'join' and $x-y=x\cdot(-y)$ where $-0=1,\ -1=0$.

In terms of your  original interpretation, the correct definition for $\oplus$ is any of the following:

- $\chi_A\oplus\chi_B:=x\mapsto \chi_A(x)+\chi_B(x)$ using the addition of $\Bbb Z_2$.
- $\chi_A\oplus\chi_B:=x\mapsto \chi_A(x)+\chi_B(x)-2\chi_A(x)\chi_B(x)$.
- $\chi_A\oplus\chi_B:=x\mapsto \max(\chi_A(x),\, \chi_B(x)) - \chi_A(x)\chi_B(x)$.
- $\chi_A\oplus\chi_B:= \chi_{A\Delta B}$ where $\Delta$ denotes *symmetric difference* of sets.

In each of the above definitions, for a particular $x\in X$, the cases $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$ are mapped to $0$ and $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ are mapped to $1$.

Using the first alternative, it is immediate that $\mathcal B$ is a ring, as it is ${\cong\Bbb Z_2}^{|X|}$.